# Force number to 3 decimals

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following code in Oracle PL/SQL:

```
    SELECT ROUND(iznos* postotak_prihod /100, 3) INTO prihod_f FROM DUAL;
           SELECT ROUND(iznos* postotak_fond /100, 3) INTO fond_f FROM DUAL;
           PP11 := prihod_f;
           SELECT ROUND(prihod_f, 2) INTO PP21 FROM DUAL;
           PP31 := PP11 - PP21;
           IF PP31 != 0 THEN
             prihod_f := prihod_f - 0.005;
             fond_f := fond_f + 0.005;
           END IF;
```

I need the values prihod_f and fond_f to be kept as 3 decimals, otherwise my calculations are incorrect and are always kept with 2 decimals, which is incorrect.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a more complete code sample. Preferably, one that we can run (remember, we cannot see your screen, nor do we know your requirements etc etc). As a minimum, you should include your variable declarations.

Comment: A test case please? We don't have your tables, nor the data. So, how to reproduce what you are stating?

Comment: Sorry, all of the variables are of type number as in pp31 NUMBER;
For example the product iznos(postotak_prihod/100) should be a number such as 28,375, the same for the product in the second row.

Comment: If you always need three decimals, why are you rounding to 2 here `ROUND(prihod_f, 2)`?

Comment: I check that in the if clause so I need that variable on 2 decimals. Prihod_f and fond_f should be on 2 decimals.

Comment: Please re-edit your question to make it into a complete anonymous block that we can run, with example inputs that demonstrate your issue. How are you outputting the data, for example? Also, if you're concerned about the impact of rounding on your output data, why are you rounding at all? Surely you'd want to keep as much info as possible right up until the final step, where you'd then apply any rounding as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're actually doing with your results, perhaps all you need is a to_char() to cast the number into a string for display purposes.

Also, there is absolutely no need for you to use the `select ... from dual`s that you've been using; PL/SQL can quite easily cope with mathematical functions, including round.

Maybe this will give you a clue as to what you need to do:

```
declare
  p_num1a number := 1.123;
  p_num2a number := 2.345;
  p_num1b number;
  p_num2b number;
  p_res number;
begin
   p_num1b := round(10/p_num1a, 3);
   dbms_output.put_line('1: p_num1b = '||p_num1b);

   p_num2b := round(10/p_num2a, 3);
   dbms_output.put_line('2: p_num2b = '||p_num2b);

   p_res := p_num1b - round(p_num1b, 2);
   dbms_output.put_line('3: p_res = '||p_res);

   if p_res != 0 then
     p_num1b := p_num1b - 0.005;
     dbms_output.put_line('4a: p_num1b = '||p_num1b);
     dbms_output.put_line('4b: p_num1b = '||to_char(p_num1b, 'fm999999999999.000'));

     p_num2b := p_num2b + 0.005;
     dbms_output.put_line('5: p_num2b = '||p_num2b);
   end if;
end;
/
```

Remember that any time you output something that's stored as a number (or date or...) onto your screen for display purposes (be it in a data grid, or via dbms_output), it's automatically being converted into a string.